# What are the ways that I can test and improve the security of my network?

Tags: networking, security, wireless-networking

I have a wlan setup with that my neighbors can probably access if they're knowledgable enough. My setup includes wireless authentication using WPA/WPA2 mixedmode, WPA-PSK pre-shared key, and enforced MAC filtering.

Comment: Consider making your question CW since there's no single best answer available.

Answer (score 2):

Mixed-mode WPA2-PSK is probably good enough, as long as your passphrase is well-chosen. If you don't really need TKIP (WPA "1") anymore, consider making it WPA2-only (that is, AES-CCMP only), because there have been some attacks against TKIP recently.

MAC address filtering is a waste of time. MAC addresses are easily discovered and spoofed. Using a "hidden" SSID (a.k.a. "non-broadcast" SSID, a.k.a. "Closed Network") is also a waste of time.

Comment: Some sources and/or references would be much welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a penetration testing system like [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/).